# User organising randomly generated numbers in ascending order game not working

Tags: python, numbers, counting

So, im trying to code a number sorting game for school. I have a random number generator, generating 6 numbers between 1 and 100. Then i have sorted the the randomly generated strain of numbers and have put that as the answer to the question. So far my code is:

```
import random

print('Please rearrange the following numbers in ascending order')
strain = []
for i in range(6):
    strain.append(random.randint(1,100))
print(strain)

sortedstrain = sorted(strain)

Answer = input('Answer Here: ')
if H1Answer == sortedstrain:
  print('correct')
else:
  print('wrong')
```

But when i input the correct answer, it still comes up as incorrect. Someone please tell me what is wrong with my code. Ill greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Where does `H1Answer` come from - that's not in your code... and your `sortedstrain` is a list of integers... how are you inputting what you have in `Answer` (which is also a string) to handle the comparison to that list?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a couple of things to get the list of random numbers to match with the user input:

```
import random

print('Please rearrange the following numbers in ascending order')
strain = []
for i in range(6):
    strain.append(random.randint(1,100))
print(str(strain)[1:-1])

sortedstrain = sorted(strain)

Answer = input('Answer Here: ')
if Answer == str(sortedstrain)[1:-1]:
    print('correct')
else:
    print('wrong')
```

```
Please rearrange the following numbers in ascending order
71, 81, 33, 74, 99, 44

Answer Here: 33, 44, 71, 74, 81, 99
correct
```

This converts the list to a string and then filters off the open and close brackets.

Comment: +1, but you should explain a bit more the problem. This answer is only suitable as a comment. Would you mind expand it a bit?

Comment: Yes, i will expand

Comment: Umm... what do you think `[Answer]` is doing there - that creates a list with a single element that's a string... that'll never equal a list of 6 integers...

Comment: You are right. I have updated the answer, and the comparison works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Input() function returns string. Your sortedstrain has int. You will have to make them compatible for a valid comparison.
I assume answer is either comma or space separated sorte numbers.

If so, you will have to break it and convert each element into int and then you can compare with the sortedstrain...

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

print('Please rearrange the following numbers in ascending order')
strain = []
for i in range(6):
    strain.append(random.randint(1,100))
print(strain)

sortedstrain = sorted(strain)

Answer = [int(x) for x in input('Answer Here: ').split()]

if Answer == sortedstrain:
  print('correct')
else:
  print('wrong')
```